# Edit the height of dynamically loaded iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter

I want to edit the height of the iframe that twitter serves to the dom after it's script function completes.  The reason why I want to to edit the height here is, I want the height of the iframe to be the same height as it's sibling element.

So I want twitteriframe.height() == mydiv.height().

However, as the iframe is loaded dynamically, I can't access it in the document.ready.  There is no click event, so what else can I do to edit the iframe height?

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the height after the frame is loaded.

```
$('#frameId').load(function () {
    // do something here
});
```

If the element is added dynamically then there's an issue - you have no control over the inserted elements (since DOM Mutation Events are deprecated), so as a workaround you could continously check for existence of such element (for example with a setInterval which is cleared after the element is found).

After it is added check the iframe's height and apply it to the second element.

Comment: that doesn't work, and I am not sure how it could, because the element isn't there yet for it to bind an event to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var queryTimeoutMS = 100;
window.setTimeout(resizeTwitterIFrame,queryTimeoutMS);
function resizeTwitterIFrame(){
  if($("#frameId").length > 0){
    //Do your stuff
  }
  else{
    window.setTimeout(resizeTwitterIFrame,queryTimeoutMS);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats really good and does seem to go into the function when the iframe has loaded, but it doesn't change the size.  I wonder if there is an issue with changing iframe sizes loaded dynamically.

Comment: How do you do it? Like so?
  
    `$("#frameId").height(size);`

Comment: no `("#frameId").attr('height',size)` since that's how it is set in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I decided instead to do it with css.  Set the height on the parent container and set it to `overflow:hidden`;